# I can't add a photo in a solution (underfull \hbox (badness 1000)

Tags: errors

```
\begin{solution}

text

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/mixtas.png}
    \label{fig:mesh2}
\end{figure}\\

more text


\end{solution}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `underfull \hbox` isn't an error, but a warning, so you can (but shouldn't) ignore it. What is probably causing that warning is the ``\\`` after `\end{figure}`. You can probably remove that.

Comment: your question is very unclear. The warning is from the mis-use of `\\ ` which you can delete, but neither the `\\ ` nor the warning are related in any way to including an image, so if the `\includegraphics` did not work that is due to some other issue but you have given no clue to allow anyone to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave no complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I can not test the following code snippet for you. Please do it yourself and report the result in a comment.

You should use `\\` never to start a new paragraph (I suppose you want to start a new paragraph after environment `figure` with `\\`. `\\` is for example used in a table to start a new line. If you need a new paragraph in usual text simply use a blank line in the tex code. In your code snippet you use a lot of blank lines (which has the function here to start a new paragraph).

So start with the following code (see that I deletes all blank lines and your used `\\`. Please see that environment `figure` starts a new parapaph with a little space before and after the figure.

```
\begin{solution}
text
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/mixtas.png}
    \label{fig:mesh2}
\end{figure}
more text
\end{solution}
```